# Understand Zip and list comprehension in python

Tags: python

I have a function "to_underscore" that takes a CamelCase string and convert it to snake_case

```
def to_underscore(string):
    index_counter = []

    if isinstance(string, int):
        return str(string)

    for i in range(len(string)):
        if string[i].isupper():
            index_counter.append(i)

    new_string = [string[i:j] for i,j in zip (index_counter,index_counter[1:] + [None])]
    string = '_'.join(new_string)

    return ''.join(c.lower() for c in string)
```

I didn't quite understand how the folowing line is executed:

```
string = "ThisIsCamelCase"
index_counter = [0,4,6,11]

// this line - >
for i,j in zip (index_counter,index_counter[1:] + [None]):
        print(i,j)

// output -> (0,4),(4,6),(6,11),(11,None)
```

what does `index_counter[1:] +[None]` means ? and why this is the output?

I understand zip and what we are trying to do, but the output is not clear.

if you can walk through the execution this will be optimal.

Comment: it's iterating over the list in pairs, instead of adding `None` to the end, you could have used `itertools.zip_longest()`

Comment: `index_counter[1:]+[None]` means slice all elements from 1 onward from `index_counter` and then append the element `None` to the slice. You might read about "python slicing" and list addition

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
index_counter = [0, 4, 6, 11]
```

Now, `index_counter[1:]` is:

```
[4, 6, 11]
```

`index_counter[1:] + [None]` is:

```
[4, 6, 11, None]
```

`zip` this with `index_counter`, and you're iterating over these pairs:

```
0   4   6   11
4   6   11  None
```

The `None` needs to be added, as `zip` would otherwise stop at the `(6, 11)` pair. Instead you could also use [`itertools.zip_longest`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/itertools.html#itertools.zip_longest).

Answer (score 0):

```
index_counter[1:] +[None]
```

This is a list concatenation, index_counter is concatenated with a list containing a `None` value. The part `[1:]`means `the sublist from index 1 to the end`. So the whole expression creates a list where the first element is removed, and a `None`is added at the end.

`zip` creates a list of pairs of the entries in the two lists with the same indices.

The end result is that there are pairs of (index, next index).

Answer (score 0):

Just for future reference, print is your friend. Try this:

```
print(index_counter)
print(index_counter[1:])
print(index_couter[1:] + [None])
# When printing a zip object (or any iterable), just cast to a list first so you can see what's in it
print(list(zip(index_counter, index_counter[1:] + [None])))
```

Chances are if you look at the output you're going to know what's going on.

Answer (score -1):

`index_counter[1:]` returns a sublist starting from element 1 (that is, the second element, since indexes start at 0).  In this case, that would be `[4,6,11]`.

Then we add a `None` element at the end, so that the two lists have the same length and we can call `zip` on them.

`zip([0,4,6,11], [4,6,11,None])` returns a number of pairs, picking one element from both lists at a time:

```
[(0,4),     # first element from both lists
 (4,6),     # second element from both lists
 (6,11),    # third element from both lists
 (11,None)] # fourth element from both lists
```

These pairs can then be used to pick out a portion of the string, from one capital letter to the next.